# React-Native style a sticky header when it sticks

Tags: styling, react-native-scrollview, react-native

I've a short question: How can I apply a different style to a sticky header in a scrollview when it sticks?
I wanna add some shadow/elevation when it sticks.

Thank you :)

## Environment

- react-native: 0.45.0

Comment: Listen to onscroll and use state to change style of the component when header sticks.

Comment: @SagarKhatri Thank you for your comment! How did I know when the header sticks? Is there a special event or a method to get the offset of a component in the scrollview?

Comment: @DanielLang did you find a way in the end?

Answer (score 5):

Currently [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/) [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.45/scrollview) component has a property called [stickyHeaderIndices](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.45/scrollview#stickyheaderindices), even in your [0.45](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.45/getting-started) version. You can use it to pass your header child index that should be sticky. After that you can use [onScroll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.45/scrollview#onscroll) event to get current scroll position and when achieve your header size add a custom style with shadow. See for the example here:

https://snack.expo.io/@fabiodamasceno/scroll-sticky-styled

or if you prefer:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

const HEADER_HEIGHT = 20;
const headerStyle = {
  backgroundColor: '#e5e5e5',
  height: HEADER_HEIGHT
}
const myShadowStyle = {
  elevation: 3,
  shadowOpacity: 0.2,
  shadowRadius: 6,
  shadowOffset: {
    height: 3,
    width: 0,
  },
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
     headerStyle : {
     ...headerStyle
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <View style={{marginTop: HEADER_HEIGHT, height: 150}}>
      <ScrollView 
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} 
          onScroll={event => {
            const y = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
            if(y >= HEADER_HEIGHT)
              this.setState({
                headerStyle:{
                    ...headerStyle,
                    ...myShadowStyle
                }
              })
            else
              this.setState({
                  headerStyle:{
                      ...headerStyle,
                  }
                })
          }}
      >
        <View style={this.state.headerStyle}>
          <Text>My Header Title</Text>
        </View>
        <Text>Item 1</Text>
        <Text>Item 2</Text>
        <Text>Item 3</Text>
        <Text>Item 4</Text>
        <Text>Item 5</Text>
        <Text>Item 6</Text>
        <Text>Item 7</Text>  
        <Text>Item 8</Text>
        <Text>Item 9</Text>
        <Text>Item 10</Text>
        <Text>Item 11</Text>
        <Text>Item 12</Text>
        <Text>Item 13</Text>
        <Text>Item 14</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach but the state is not updating as desired, too slow for my taste

Answer (score 0):

Thnx me later..!   The final code should be looking like this. This is the most basic example that we can have to dig into animations using react-native.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  Animated,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import Colors from "../../../../config/color/color";

const App = () => {
  const scrollPosition = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const minHeaderHeight = 70;
  const maxHeaderHeight = 200;

  const headerHeight = scrollPosition.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 500],
    outputRange: [maxHeaderHeight, minHeaderHeight],
    extrapolate: "clamp",
  });
  const opacity = scrollPosition.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100, 200],
    outputRange: [1, 0.5, 0],
    extrapolate: "clamp",
  });
  const size = scrollPosition.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100, 200, 300, 400],
    outputRange: [20, 17, 15, 13, 11],
    extrapolate: "clamp",
  });
  const imageHeight = scrollPosition.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 400],
    outputRange: [100, 50],
    extrapolateLeft: "identity",
    extrapolateRight: "clamp",
  });
  const imagePosition = scrollPosition.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 400],
    outputRange: [(37 * Dimensions.get("window").width) / 100, 0],
    extrapolateLeft: "identity",
    extrapolateRight: "clamp",
  });
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            // position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            zIndex: 10,
            height: headerHeight,
            backgroundColor: "lightblue",
          }}
        >
          <Animated.Text
            style={{
              opacity: opacity,
              fontSize: size,
            }}
          >
            Header
          </Animated.Text>
          <Animated.Image
            style={{
              height: imageHeight,
              width: imageHeight,
              borderRadius: imageHeight,
              transform: [{ translateX: imagePosition }],
            }}
            source={{
              uri: "https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png",
            }}
          />
        </Animated.View>
        <Animated.ScrollView
          onScroll={Animated.event(
            [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollPosition } } }],
            { useNativeDriver: false }
          )}
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={[styles.scrollView]}
        >
          {Array.from(Array(100), (e, key) => {
            return <Text key={key}>Item {key}</Text>;
          })}
        </Animated.ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
});

export default App;
```